# MSBuild not resolving references pointing outside of GAC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am new to C# so it may be possible that I am not asking the right questions.  Please bear with me.

I have a solution and within that solution is a project that is executing an SSIS package remotely.  After some research I discovered that in order to do so I needed to create some references to DLLs that were "outside" of the GAC (General Assembly Catalog ?).  The following assemblies were referenced:

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

When I clean and build the solution from within Visual Studio 2015, everything builds fine.  However when I call MSBuild on the solution from my deployment script, I get many errors saying that the references do not exist. For example, here is one of those errors:

> "C:\TestModule\SSISTests\SSISTests.csproj" (default target) (10) -> (CoreCompile target) -> SSISTests.cs(78,17): error CS0012: The type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ISfcConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not
> referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. [C:\TestModule\SSISTests\SSISTests.csproj]

Is there an option I am not passing to MSBuild that would solve this problem?  This is not a dependency issue (I don't think) because no other projects are needed by this project - just these SQL Server assemblies.

Comment: Just as Michael suggest, how about the result just build the SSISTest.csproj project rather than the solution? And have you try to add the 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ISfcConnection' reference to that project?

Comment: The references are there as I stated in my original post.  I will have to try building just the project file with MS build to see what happens

Comment: Leo - I see what you mean now - yes for some reason the SDK was referencing other dlls that I did not have a reference for and it was working within VS but not when I called MS Build - not clear why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your csproj file and check to see if that DLL is correctly referenced. Also, see if you can run MSBuild against just the csproj and not the sln. Might be a pathing issue.

Comment: I think you may be correct - There are two of these references in the csproj file that have something called a "HintPath" element and it is using a relative path.  How can I correct this programatically?

Example: ..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Comment: Also when I do a Release build instead of a Debug build, the DLLs don't copy and everything is clean.  However does that imply this will not be able to run on a different system?  I want everything included in a release folder that I would need to run it on any other system

Comment: Can you edit the path to the DLL manually, save it, then run MSBuild against the csproj and tell me what happens? Use a relative path for the hint.

Comment: It was a pathing issue, I'm sorry I forgot to get back to this.  I removed and re-added the references and it worked.  Something got screwed up when I moved the code.